# iOS-charts Pie chart crashes in Xcode 7.1

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I was doing a tutorial on AppCoda for iOS-charts the bar chart portion on the app worked fine but the pie chart portion crashes with the the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping a optional value. It crashes on this command pieChartView.data = pieChartData. Here is the code:

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries)

    let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartDataSet.label = ""
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData

    var colors: [UIColor] = []

     colors.append(UIColor.greenColor())
     colors.append(UIColor.blueColor())
     colors.append(UIColor.blackColor())

    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
}
```

anyone have any idea why??

Comment: We will never know unless you give the stack trace

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever figure this out?